# Access a page's HTML

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Is it possible to take a link and access its HTML code through that link? For example I would like to take a link from Amazon and put it within my own HTML code, use JavaScript to `getElementsByClassName` to get the price from that link and display it back into my HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You could do a GET request to the Amazon page that will give you the html in the response from there you'll have a string now you'll need to format it, last time I used the node module jsdom to do that.

In more detail:

HTTP is a protocol that we use to request data from the server, I've wrote an explanatory node js script:

```js
const https = require('https');
const JSD = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = JSD;
const zlib = require('zlib');

// The http get request
https.get('https://www.amazon.com', (response) => {
  html = '';

  // we need this because amazon is tricky and encodes the response so it is smaller hence it is faster to send
  let gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
  response.pipe(gunzip);

  // we need this to get the full html page since it is too big to send in one amazon divides it to chunks
  gunzip.on('data', (chunk) => {
    html += chunk.toString();
  });

  // when the transmittion finished we can do wathever we want with it
  gunzip.on('end', () => {
    let amazon = new JSDOM(html);
    console.log(amazon.window.document.querySelector('html').innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to go in more detail about how to do this? I'm just a Year 1 Software Engineering student and this isn't even in my syllabus, just doing this out of self interest.

Comment: As you asked I went into more detail